# How did Emmet build the Double Decker couch?

Tags: the-lego-movie

In The LEGO Movie, if Emmet was not yet a Master Builder then how did he build the double decker couch inside the submarine?

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). I'm not entirely sure what you are asking here. Could you please flesh out the question a little more? Do you want to know how he could build it or why could suddenly build something or where he took the parts from in the submarine? Or do you just want to know how this couch is actually constructed from what parts (i.e. a construction plan)? The former seems to be answerable just by his newly found power/esteem/creativity as builder. And I'm not sure the latter would be entirely on-topic here.

Comment: I am quite sure he was not a Master Builder by this time.

Comment: You might want to add that into your question to give it a little more substance then. That being said, wasn't this whole scene about showing that he had the potential for a Master Builder within him, however small (though, that could be put into a possible answer once the question is clearer).

Comment: Emmet had no problem building the double-decker couch is because honestly that idea was just the worst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because he's thought about it before. When they were inside his mind he was able to build one easy enough without much brain power but struggled to build other, more complicated objects.

Plus he talks like he has thought over the couch before thinking it was a good idea which could help prove that he even may of thought how you could build one and doesn't need to be a master builder to build this object.